# ErrortTransforming a bootstrap theme to worpress CMS

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a bootstrap premium theme with multiple stylesheet and js files. I want to use worpress as its CMS, I followed all the neccessary steps but got stock while trying to include the global wp_head()

Comment: Hmm I wonder if there's a memory leak? Perhaps use `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` to temporarily remove the memory limit.

Comment: There is no leak, I suspect it is the head() call that carries my css files

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new theme and place all the required css/js file within the header.php file.
Include the themes default css file

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">`

Include other files required:

`<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/phone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width:900px)">`

Comment: with implimentation, will there be need for ```add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new2w_theme_styles');```

Comment: The whole declared uri in the functions folder, will there be any need for that code with your own suggestion. If I go by your inline method, there will be no need declaring links in function.php. Please help me clarify this, thanks in advance

Comment: this worked <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">, I will continue with the rest, thanks a bunch @jeff, you saved my day last minute

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was a syntax problem caused by a missing semi column ";"